# How to change string to int in logql grafana

Tags: grafana-loki, logql, fluent-plugin-grafana-loki

|label_format num=`{{102}}`
|label_format num2 =  `{{90}}`
| label_format ans= `{{if gt .num .num2 }}good {{else}} bad {{end}}`
| line_format `{{.ans}}`

I have created two labels and assigned values to them.When I perform the gt operation the output shows bad .Its considering the value of num and num2 as string while performing gt operation.

I want the comparison to be done on integer format and the output should be good.

I